# Extension on shifting or arithemtic operations in standard C

Tags: c, c99, c11

Sorry for bad English.

```
uint16_t a, c;
uint8_t b = 0xff;

a = b<<8;
c = b*10;
```

What is value of `a` and `c` we get? What is situation with arbitrary integer types?

Comment: Shifting by equal to or more than the data-type is UB. But I don't think it applies here because `b` will first be promoted to `int`.

Comment: (So the result will be a = 0xff00 and b = 2550 by standard).

Comment: @Mysticial, perhaps you should make that comment an answer. Make sure to expand the abbreviation for undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uint16_t a, c;
uint8_t b = 0xff;

a = b<<8;
```

First, the integer promotions are performed on the arguments of `<<`. The constant `8` is an `int` and thus is not converted. Since the conversion rank of `uint8_t` is smaller than that of `int`, and all values of `uint8_t` are representable as `int`s, `b` is converted - preserving its value - to `int`. The resulting `int` value is then shifted left by eight bits.

If `int` is only 16 bits wide, the value `0xff * 2^8` is not representable as an `int`, and then the shift invokes undefined behaviour - 6.5.7 (4) in n1570 and C99:

> If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Otherwise, the result is `255*256 = 65280 = 0xFF00`. Since that value is representable in the type of `a`, the conversion of the `int` result of the shift to `uint16_t` preserves the value; if the result were out of range (e.g. if the shift distance were 9 [and `int` wide enough]), it would be reduced modulo `2^16` to obtain a value in the range `0` to `2^16 - 1` of `uint16_t`.

```
c = b*10;
```

The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands of `*`. Both operands have an integer type, thus first the integer promotions are performed. Since `10` is an `int` and all values of `b`'s type are representable as an `int`, the integer promotions give both operands the same type, `int`, and the usual arithmetic conversions don't require any further conversions. The multiplication is done at type `int`, its result, `2550`, is again representable in the type of `c`, so the conversion to `uint16_t` that is done before storing the value in `c` preserves the value.

> What is situation with arbitrary integer types?

For `<<`:

1. integer promotions; values/expressions of an integer type whose conversion rank is less than or equal to that of `int` (and `unsigned int`) [integer types with width `<=` that of `(unsigned) int`], and bitfields of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int` and `unsigned int` are converted to `int` or `unsigned int` (`int` if that can represent all values of the original type, `unsigned int` otherwise).
2. If the (promoted) right operand (shift distance) is negative or greater than or equal to the width (number of value bits plus sign bits; there is either one sign bit or none) of the (promoted) left operand, the behaviour is undefined. If the value of the (promoted) left operand is negative, the behaviour is undefined. If the type of the (promoted) left operand is unsigned, the result is `value * 2^distance`, reduced modulo `2^width`. If the type of the (promoted) left operand is signed and the value nonnegative, the result is `value * 2^distance` if that is representable in the type, the behaviour is undefined otherwise.
3. If no undefined behaviour occurred in 2., the result is converted to the type of the variable it is stored in.

   - If the target type is `_Bool` (or an alias thereof), a nonzero result is converted to 1, a zero result to 0, otherwise
   - If the result can be represented in the target type, its value is preserved, otherwise
   - If the target type is unsigned, the result is reduced modulo `2^width`, otherwise
   - the result is converted in an implementation-defined manner or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

For `*`:

1. The usual arithmetic conversions are performed, so that both (converted) operands have the same type.
2. The multiplication is performed at the resulting type; if that is a signed integer type and the multiplication overflows, the behaviour is undefined.
3. The result is converted to the target type in the same manner as above.

---

That's how the abstract machine is defined, if the implementation can achieve the same results (where the behaviour is defined) in another manner, it can do as it pleases under the as-if rule.